# Separating a dataframe string column into two columns: one with multiple text words, and one numeric amount

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that has text (multiple words), then a single number (numeric amount). They are separated by spaces. How to separate these into two columns?

```
1. Special Education Benefit 1,400.00
2. Accidental Death 123,000.00
3. Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident 350
4. Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident 250
5. Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident 150
6. Accidental Death 65,000.00
7. Special Education Benefit 1,000.00
```

Required Output:

```
     Column1                                                  Column2
   
1.   Special Education Benefit                                1,400.00
2.   Accidental Death                                         123,000.00
3.   Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident                     350
4.   Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident                     250
5.   Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident                     150
6.   Accidental Death                                         65,000.00
7.   Special Education Benefit                                1,000.00
```

So:
"Special Education" and "1400.00" in different columns,
"Accidental Death" and "123,000.00" in different columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do `rsplit`

```
df.col.str.rsplit(' ', n=1,expand=True)
```

Comment: But this separates them in two columns, on the basis of space, so i get in column1: Special and in Column2  : Education Benefit 1,400.00..

Comment: @karan rsplit , not split

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that (I assume the first column is called '0'):

```
df[0].str.extract(r"^(\d+)\.(.*)\s([0-9.,]+)$")
```

The result is:

```
   0                                      1           2
0  1              Special Education Benefit    1,400.00
1  2                       Accidental Death  123,000.00
2  3   Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident         350
3  4   Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident         250
4  5   Blanket Medical Indemnity - Accident         150
5  6                       Accidental Death   65,000.00
6  7              Special Education Benefit    1,000.00
```

Comment: I've been trying to use this one, but all i'm getting is 'NAN'. any suggestion?

Comment: what's the name of the columns you're trying to 'split' into other columns?